# WordPress blocking polling request when signed into Admin

Tags: ajax, hooks, wp-admin

I've setup a polling script in js that sends an `XMLHttpRequest` to the server to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` (yes, legacy, I know) at a fixed interval of x seconds. The response returned by that request from the server corresponds to a simple and minimal JSON.

It was all working good, until I've noticed the following:

- When I login to my platform (on the frontend) and access the profile page, the polling starts.
- It all works perfectly, BUT, as soon as I login to the wp-admin in another tab within the same browser, the next polling request fails, with a 403 client error, and `-1` response from the server. From my experience, `wp-ajax` answers with `-1` when it cannot authenticate the client, for example when the nonce is wrong (which obviously is also indicated by `403`). But why is this happening? Does the login to the `wp-admin` section somehow invalidate a certain cookie that is also used on the frontend tab for authentication? That's the only thing I could imagine, as the ajax request which can only be triggered by the frontend must be hooked to both:
- the `wp_ajax_{action}` hook
- the `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` hook

***IMPORTANT NOTE***

JUST TO BE CLEAR ONCE AGAIN: MY AJAX CALLBACK IS CURRENTLY HOOKED TO BOTH HOOKS, AND THE ABOVE-MENTIONED HAPPENS!!!!!!!

So actually my `wp_ajax_{action}` is tied to the change if a client is logged in to the admin area, so I'm wondering if that's causing the issue.

I'm actually wondering if it is even necessary to register exclusive frontend calls (so for clients who have totally nothing to do with wp admin) to both the `wp_ajax_` AND the `wp_ajax_nopriv` hooks? Why is it not enough to simply hook to the `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` hook for exclusive frontend requests? That's at least what it says [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/#more-information), but so many articles out there always state that you should hook your ajax requests to both hooks. Why??

As I understand it, the `is_user_logged_in()` function, called via the `wp_ajax_{$action}` hook, triggers if the client making the request is logged in to the wp admin dashboard.

Hence, ajax calls that must be triggered from within the wp admin panel should be registered via the `wp_ajax_{$action}` hook, and ajax calls that are triggered from the frontend and have totally nothing to do with wp-admin, but are like simple REST interactions of your platform users with your platform server, should be registered via the `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` hook, no?

But that as a side-note, anyone has an idea why my issue is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Hence, ajax calls that must be triggered from within the wp admin
> panel should be registered via the `wp_ajax_{$action}` hook, and ajax
> calls that are triggered from the frontend and have totally nothing to
> do with wp-admin, but are like simple REST interactions of your
> platform users with your platform server, should be registered via the
> `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` hook, no?

No.

`wp_ajax_` is used for logged in users. `wp_ajax_nopriv_` is used for logged out users. It has nothing to do with whether you're in the admin panel or not. It's only whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Logged in to what? Because under the hood, wp_ajax_{$action} uses `is_user_logged_in() `

Comment: "Since our AJAX exchange is for the plugin’s settings page, the user must be logged in. If you recall from the jQuery section, the action: value is "my_tag_count". This means our action hook tag will be wp_ajax_my_tag_count. If our AJAX exchange were to be utilized by users who were not currently logged in, the action hook tag would be wp_ajax_nopriv_my_tag_count." Extract of the official wp developer handbook. Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Logged in means has entered their username and password and is authenticated with a cookie. They can still be logged in and looking at the front-end of your site. That's what `is_user_logged_in()` means. It doesn't mean 'is currently looking at `wp-admin/` (that's `is_admin()`).

Comment: Yes of course, that's what I meant. Generally, you don't give your platform frontend users access to your wordpress admin area. That's why I meant you should use the `wp_ajax_{$action}` hook for admin-related operations, while there should be no need to register the calls for your frontend users on that same hook, as they should totally not be able to access your admin dahsboard! That's why I'm saying `wp_ajax_{$action}` for admin-related stuff like custom post editing functions etc, and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` for interactions of your clients with your API endpoints. Makes sense, no?

Comment: And I've setup my own login system logic for the platform / frontend, so `is_user_logged_in()` returns false even for frontend users that are logged in to the platform (and obviously not to the wp admin dashboard). In this case, do you still see a problem with my logic?

Comment: “Makes sense, no?” No, it doesn’t. `nopriv` _will not work_ if the user is logged in. So it would not work for admin users previewing the front end.l unless it was also hooked to `wp_ajax_`.

Comment: I know it doesn't, read my question carefully plz, I'm referring to frontend users who are NOT logged in to wp, where I use wp_ajax_nopriv, if that makes sense. So I guess that's a yes then.

Comment: You’re just being wilfully ignorant now. You’re complaining that an AJAX request stops working when you log in from another tab. _I’ve just explained why_. The nopriv hook will not work if you’re logged in! Being logged in just means you have an authenticated cookie. How many more times will you make me repeat that?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, we misunderstood each other. My hook question was separated from my ajax question, they're two different problems. Of course I know that, if I logged in to wp admin, I keep being recognized to wp as logged in, even if looking at the fronted, due to the cookie. My questions were A) if the presence of that cookie may cause the request to fail (as my request is currently hooked to BOTH HOOKS!!), and how to use the hooks in general. I get that I need to hook wp_ajax_ too if I logged in and subsequently access the feontend and want that to work

Comment: But that was never really my question, as only I as a developer am facing this scenario, and I can easily simply from now on open wp admin in another browser while developing, if that allows a more concrete logic of my ajax hooking. You see what I mean? So my final question is basically: do you understand why my polling request succeeds perfectly, but, as soon as I open another tab where I login to wp admin, the request fails with 403, response 0? The ajax callback is currently hooked to BOTH hooks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Was it you who just downvoted my question? :')